# Unable to assign value to variable

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm pretty new android developer and I'm facing a weird problem. I'm trying to create a simple validation test to define whether an input is valid and username is not in us, or the opposite. I tried al kinds of thing like creating a static bollean 'isValid' variable and assign it or to use methods like setValid() to assign it but nothing seems to do the job.

I am certain the the code is being processed (debug it) but nothing changes, it's stuck on false.

Please share your wisdom with me.

```
public class Registration extends Fragment {
    public boolean isValid=false;

    public Registration() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Button bDone = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bDone);
        bDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // pressed when finished entering personal details
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText fName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
                final EditText lName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
                final EditText id = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etID);
                final EditText email = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
                final EditText uName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etRegUsername);
                final EditText pWord = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etRegPassword);

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Account");

                String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                String emailAddress;

                ParseObject dsAccount = new ParseObject("Account");
                dsAccount.put("firstName", fName.getText().toString());
                dsAccount.put("lastName", lName.getText().toString());
                dsAccount.put("ID", id.getText().toString());
                dsAccount.put("Email", email.getText().toString());
                dsAccount.put("username", uName.getText().toString());
                dsAccount.put("password", pWord.getText().toString());

                emailAddress = email.getText().toString();

                if (fName.getText().toString().length() == 0
                        || lName.getText().toString().length() == 0
                        || id.getText().toString().length() == 0
                        || email.getText().toString().length() == 0
                        || uName.getText().toString().length() == 0
                        || pWord.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    // at least one of the fields is empty
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"One or more fields are missing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!emailAddress.matches(emailPattern)) {
                    // email address not valid
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // email address valid

                    query.whereEqualTo("username", uName.getText().toString());
                    query.whereEqualTo("password", pWord.getText().toString());
                    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        public void done(ParseObject Account, ParseException e) {
                            if (Account == null) {
                                isValid=true;//***this is the code that doesnt happen**
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Username is already in use",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (isValid){//**this is the code that supposed to respond**
                    dsAccount.saveInBackground();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"New account saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem may be with if (Account == null) {. I mean what is this "Account" that you are comparing?

Comment: I'm trying to find the username in database, in order to prevent overwriting it. Account is an object in my database

Comment: Thanks to krodmannix for the great answer!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the snippet you posted is that `query.getFirstInBackground` is executed in background, and you check isValid value when the `done`  is called. So you probably want to execute

```
  dsAccount.saveInBackground();
  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"New account saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

when `done(ParseObject Account, ParseException e) {` is called, instead of setting a flag. Also, only the UI Thread can touch the ui

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the Asynchronous method `getFirstInBackground`, you cannot use your code sequentially, like you are trying to do here. The `getFirstInBackground` method fires on another thread, then continues along - so essentially, you `if` statement checking for `isValid` fires too soon. Place this portion of the code inside your asynchronous call like so:

```
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(ParseObject Account, ParseException e) {
                        if (Account == null) {
                            isValid=true;//***this is the code that doesnt happen**
                            dsAccount.saveInBackground();
                            makeAToast("New account saved", mActivity); // Explained down below
                        } else {
                            makeAToast("Username is already in use", mActivity);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and make `context` a global variable in your class, like `Context context = this` before `onCreate()` is called. Make an `Activity` type variable as well in the same way: `Activity mActivity = this`.

Because you can't call `Toast`, which is a UI component from a non-UI thread (because you are saving in the background thread), try something like this:

```
public void makeAToast(String inText, Activity myActivity) {
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        myActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,inText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try to use your code but I dont quite understand the second part of it, th makeToast method.
What is exactly the myactivity.this.runOnUiThread?
Eclipse does not recognize it even after replacing myactivity.this with getActivity()

Comment: Do you understand the Async part? The reason this method must exist is that only on the UI thread can UI objects be interacted with - Toast is a piece of the UI. So, we must tell the background thread to run on the UI thread and post a Toast. Try replacing `myactivity.this` with `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the UI. But still doesn't managae to add the code without getting errors. runOnUiThread is unrecognized as well as runnable(). Is it possible that i'm missing something?

Comment: Well, glad that you understand the concept behind it. I'm missing a subtly - myactivity.this should not be of Context type, but should be of the type Activity, because runOnUiThread is a method of the Activity class. Try replacing it with `Registration.this` - you need to reference your Activity where the UI will appear. Also (and I'll edit my post), runnable should be capitalized to `Runnable()`, as its an instance of the Runnable class.

Comment: Not to double post, but another possibility if `Registration.this` doesn't work is to create an Activity variable (before onCreate()) like this `Activity myActivity = this` and pass this in as an argument into the `makeToast` method, than replacing what calls `runOnUiThread` with this variable of the `Activity` type.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That worked just great!!
I've learnd alot from this!

Comment: Glad it worked - would you mind accepting this answer if it worked for you? Thanks!

Comment: I would gladly do it but because I'm new here I dont have enough reputation to do so...   :(

Comment: @evyamiz I'm not sure there is a restriction for accepting answers based on reputation

Comment: @krodmanix Maybe I don't understand what u mean. Can u guide me how to do that?